# UITableViewCell labels/images with no content still take up space

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom tableviewcell:

[image]

But some of my users may not have an email or timestamp.  Currently those labels show up as blanks, but they take up room.  Is there a way (in storyboarding) to have labels without values not take up room?

I also have the same problem w/ image.  If I don't have an image, what is the right way to hide/remove that from that cell?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

to return the appropriate height after examining if there is data or not.

Comment: if I hide email label the label still takes up space.  Will heightForRowAtIndexPath really going to fix that.  Especially if timestamp is underneath.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some code for this.

As @Mundi said, implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` if you want to set the height of cell under different conditions.

However, what you may want to do is in 
`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return 0 if there is no record at all.

And in 
`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` remove the image when you build the cell.

Also remember to do `[tableView reloadData];` every time the data is updated.

Comment: 'However, what you may want to do is in  tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: return 0 if there is no record at all.'  There is data maybe just not for a label in that cell.  Still very confused as tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath seems like it adjusts the cell height.  If no email I need that label to take up no space such that the timestamp field moves up.

Comment: I can see what you are trying to do here. Two ways of doing this. The lazier way is to use just 1 label instead of 3, and use `"\n"` to separate lines. This way if you want just two lines you can easily do that. A (much) harder but (much) more flexible way is to embed another `UITableView` in the cell.

Comment: possible to just create the entire uitableviewcell programmatically?

Comment: It's possible but I would avoid it unless I absolutely have to do it. It just sounds like a big pain.